# How can I post the request to my url on moving from one tab to another tab in a html page which has multiple tabs using django

Tags: javascript, html, django, tabs

```
I have four tabs in my html page(index.html).
1.Dashboard
2.Inventory
3.Log Analysis
4.Configuration Analysis

I have four html pages for each of four tabs
1.Index.html
2.Inventory.html
3.Log.html
4.Configuration.html
```

How can I post the data to the server when I am moving from Inventory tab to Log Analysis tab.
I am using a javascript file named script.js to handle my Inventory tab JS Code. I want to request the data from server and show it in log.html file. To do that, I should be able to post the data from any tab when I clicked on it. How can I do that.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using jquery UI tab? You can attach events.

Comment: @Apul Gupta, Yes, I m using jquery UI tabs. Could u please let me know what events I can attach?

Comment: Just go read the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/ I'm not trying to be rude or mean, but Stack Overflow is not a "do my work for me" site. You have to put some effort in to get some effort out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help you:

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-activate

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  activate: function( event, ui ) {
   // Your code will go here

  }
});
```